# Send audio file and text file through email as attachment in cordova ios & android app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, email-attachments

I am developing cordova 3.2 based ios & android mobile app. I have recorded audio file and text file on phone memory. I want to send these two files as a email attachment to certain email address.

Is anyone knows how to do this?